# Error for Constraint added to Field does not show for field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I dynamically generate a form and add constraints (i.e. [`Choice`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html)).

```
$builder->add('test', 'choice', [
    'choices' => [1, 'one', 2 => 'two'],
    'required' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'error_bubbling' => true,
    'cascade_validation' => true,
    'label' => 'this_is_a_test',
    'multiple' => false,
    'constraints' => [
        new NotBlank([
            'groups' => ['Default']
        ]),
        new Choice([
            'min' => 1,
            'choices' => [1, 2],
            'groups' => ['Default']
        ])
    ]
]);
```

When submitting the form with empty data, the error shows up for the form, not the element of the form where i added the constraint (checked in profiler as well).

There is not Option `atPath` for those constraints and i add them directly to the field, so i do not get why they show up for the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the [error_bubbling](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#error-bubbling) option does (which you set to `true` in your form type):

> If `true`, any errors for this field will be passed to the parent field or form. For example, if set to `true` on a normal field, any errors for that field will be attached to the main form, not to the specific field.